# Trying to remove indicator-KDEconnect

Tags: command-line, error-handling, kde-connect

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSzc2.jpg)

Okay been trying remove this and it keeps giving me some trouble, tried many many commands and it usually has this error.

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you get the error message is because the PPA maintainer has not updated the packages inside it for the release of Ubuntu you're running.

However the good news is, Martin Wimpress has a maintained PPA which does have an up to date KDE Connect Indicator package for Ubuntu 20.10.

[https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-kdeconnect](https://launchpad.net/%7Eflexiondotorg/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-kdeconnect)

You can remove the .list file for the PPA you no longer need, which you will find in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.